# How do I get a table of AABB's?

Tags: java, aabb

**I am not sure if this is the right site to put this question on.**

What would be a good, time saving method to reference an AABB with an integer id in Java programming language?

AABB class:

```
public class AABB {
private EndPoint[] min = new EndPoint[3];
private EndPoint[] max = new EndPoint[3];
private int entityId = 0;
private Boolean isStatic = false;
private static Map<Integer, AABB> table = new HashMap<>();
private Vector3f pos;
private int id = 0;

public AABB(Vector3f min,Vector3f max,Vector3f pos,int entityId,Boolean isStatic) {
    this.min[0] = new EndPoint(true,pos.x - min.x,id);
    this.min[1] = new EndPoint(true,pos.y - min.y,id);
    this.min[2] = new EndPoint(true,pos.z - min.z,id);

    this.max[0] = new EndPoint(false, pos.x + max.x,id);
    this.max[1] = new EndPoint(false,pos.y + max.y,id);
    this.max[2] = new EndPoint(false,pos.z + max.z,id);
    this.pos = pos;
    this.entityId = entityId;
    this.id = UniqueIdentifier.nextInt();
    this.isStatic = isStatic;
}
public static AABB setAABB(AABB aabb) {
    return table.put(Integer.valueOf(aabb.getId()), aabb);
}

public static AABB getAABB(int id) {
    return table.get(Integer.valueOf(id));

}

public static AABB getAABB(EndPoint endpoint) {
    return getAABB(endpoint.getId());

}



@Override
public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    if(arg0 == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if((arg0 == null) || !(arg0 instanceof AABB)) {
        return false;
    }

    AABB aabb = null;
    try {
        aabb = (AABB) arg0;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return ((aabb.getMax() == getMax()) && (aabb.getMin() == getMin()) && (aabb.isStatic() == isStatic || aabb.isStatic().equals(isStatic())) && (aabb.getPos() == getPos()) && (aabb.getId() == getId()) && (aabb.getEntityId() == getEntityId()));



}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17;
    hash += 5 * ((Boolean) isStatic).hashCode();
    hash += 5 * ( min == null ? 0 : min.hashCode());
    hash += 5 * ( max == null ? 0 : max.hashCode());
    hash += 5 * ( pos == null ? 0 : pos.hashCode());
    hash += 5 * id;
    hash += 5 * entityId;
    return hash;
}


}
```

SAP class:

```
 public class SAP {
public static List<EndPoint> xaxis = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<EndPoint> yaxis = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<EndPoint> zaxis = new ArrayList<>();
private SAP() {}

public static void addObject(AABB aabb) {
    if(!PairManager.isInPairs(aabb)) {
        xaxis.add(aabb.getMax()[0]);
        xaxis.add(aabb.getMin()[0]);

        yaxis.add(aabb.getMax()[1]);
        yaxis.add(aabb.getMin()[1]);


        zaxis.add(aabb.getMax()[2]);
        zaxis.add(aabb.getMin()[2]);

                    // Where i set table
        AABB.setAABB(aabb);
    }
}


private static boolean  intersects(AABB a,AABB b, int axis)
{
            // Where exeption is thrown a and b == null
    return !(a.getMax()[axis].getValue() < b.getMin()[axis].getValue() || b.getMax()[axis].getValue() < a.getMin()[axis].getValue());
}

private static boolean intersects(AABB a,AABB b) {
    return intersects(a,b,0) && intersects(a,b,1) && intersects(a,b,2);
}

}
```

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt deleted offernding sentence

Comment: Hehe I would not have said "offending" but thanks for that :)

Comment: Could you add a bit more info about what you're trying to do? Is the intention to check a single AABB against all of the other AABB and you want to do it in an efficient way?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt no the intention is to reference an aabb with its id

Comment: A `Map<Integer, AABB>` should do, I think.

Comment: @Pateman I tried that and whenever I try to reference the aabb's I get a NullPointerException

Comment: You need to show us what code you're using, what code uses it and where the exception gets thrown. Questions like these aren't helpful as we can't guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Pateman,@Tyyppi_77 I edited my post

Comment: There seems to be a lot of unrelated code now. Try to reduce the amount of code to a minimal amount where your issue is reproducible.

Comment: @Macky ben Jonah, I think that the cause is that your `EndPoint`s always have the id of zero. Try moving the creation of them after you've assigned the id using `UniqueIdentifier`.

Comment: @Pateman That works but please put it in answer

Comment: Done. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the cause is that your `EndPoint`s always have the id of zero. Try moving the creation of them after you've assigned the id using `UniqueIdentifier`.